# Can I read a smartcard in a virtual machine?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, smartcard

My employer requires a smartcard to login to their web-based remote working platform.  I want to access this platform by using a Remote Desktop Connection on to my Windows 7 Virtual Machine, with the smartcard plugged into my home PC.  However, whilst I can see the smartcard on my home PC, it doesn't appear in the virtual machine, despite me having "Smart Cards" enabled in the Local Resources page of Remote Desktop Connection.  Is it possible to get this working?

EDIT: This [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/doxley/archive/2010/02/18/smartcard-needing-drivers-in-order-to-be-smart.aspx) describes how to achieve this, by manually installing the Smartcard minidrivers in the guest VM OS.  I am now getting an error: "A smart card was detected but is not the one required for the current operation.  The smart card you are using may be missing required drive software or a required certificate".

Comment: I am making a Remote Desktop Connection to the Virtual Machine